# How to replace some content and keep other content in the same wrapper using jQuery...

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery and I would like to replace some content in a wrapper div, but keep other content intact. Using my example, I want to retain `.link`, but replace all the child elements. Using `html()` on the parent will replace everything: `$('.parent').html(data)`

Is there a way to keep the `.link` div without messing around with the structure? I'll change the structure if there is a good reason to, but let's otherwise assume I have to call the data replacement funciton on the `.parent` div.

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child-1">
   </div>
   <div class="child-2">
   </div>
   <!-- etc... total number changes -->

   <div class="link">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".parent div").not(".link").replaceWith(data);
```

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it's the simplest one. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".parent").find("div").not(".link").remove();
$(".parent").prepend("<div>hello world</div>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
 $('.parent div').filter(':not(.link)').wrapAll('<div>').parent('div').html('data');
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/N4FGX/